# Why am I getting duplicate RSpec test fails?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake

When I get a test fail, I get duplicate errors from slightly different directory paths. Example of this is:

```
  1) Bike when created should not be broken
     Failure/Error: it { is_expected.not_to be_broken }
       expected #<Bike:0x007fb5c7061448> to respond to `broken?`
     # /Users/paulwallis/Projects/sudo_boris_bikes/spec/bike_spec.rb:4:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) Bike when created should not be broken
     Failure/Error: it { is_expected.not_to be_broken }
       expected #<Bike:0x007fb5c70f26a0> to respond to `broken?`
     # ./spec/bike_spec.rb:4:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

They are the same error, but are using only a part of the directory path. Are they duplicated?

Comment: how are you running your tests?

Comment: seems like you're running `rspec spec ~/Projects/sudo_boris_bikes/spec`

Comment: Anthony - Run by Rake.  Interestingly I don't get the duplicated error when I run RSpec only when I run Rake?